# What is the exact time of of render() being invoke in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The output of the code below is:

```
render
after setState
render
setTimeout after setState
```

Why render() is called after the handleClick() and before the setTimeout callback function?
What is the exact time of of render() being invoke?

```
    var React = require('react'),
      ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

    var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
      getInitialState:function(){
        return {
          time:new Date()
        };
      },
      handleClick:function(e){
        this.setState({time:new Date()});
        setTimeout(function(){
          console.log('setTimeout after setState');
        },0);
        console.log('after setState');
      },
      render: function() {
        console.log('render');
        return (
          <p onClick={this.handleClick}>
            It is {this.state.time.toTimeString()}
          </p>
        );
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <HelloWorld />,
      document.getElementById('example')
    );
```

Comment: Render is called on state change. Idea being you want to change the view given different app state. The console log output seems to be what to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

*render* is being called before your anonymous function as you call *setState* before *setTimeout* and, for these purposes, Javascript is single threaded.

---

The following is what is happening in your code:

1. You define a class Hello World.
2. Somewhere you call *ReactDOM.render*
3. React sets the state from your *getInitialState* method.
4. Your component is rendered.
5. You click on your 



    element.
6. *handleClick* fires with the React normalised event.
7. You set state and React marks itself to re-render.
8. You *setTimeout*, which happens to include a *console.log*
9. Javascript is single threaded, so the next thing to fire is *render*
10. *render* has finished, so the anonymous function in *setTimeout* can fire.

On top of all of this, there is no guarantee that the order that you see output in the JS console is definitely the order that they were sent anyway.

Comment: I am confused about that the render is not invoked immediately after setState but after the end of handleClick so that 'after setState' is log before the second 'render'.

Comment: Calling *setState* just sets some object properties that React then uses to decide to re-render (or not). As Javascript is single threaded, it cannot render while other code is already being run and must wait until it is finished, hence the *console.log* in *handleClick* fires first, then *render* gets called.

Comment: @Weapon do you have any other questions about this?